# ReactJS _ NextJs - My console.log returns me: "onmozfullscreenchange is deprecated"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, mozilla

I have searched in my folder but nowhere there is a "onmozfullscreenchange" defined. Maybe someone can explain us what that means? On [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1504946) there is some obscure discussion like that, I think they talk about the browser and some patch but it have nothing to do with my code I think.

I have updated my package but the warning still occurs,

any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Hi, what is your version of react? Can you paste some of the code?

Comment: okay I will try to detect the code sequence's concerned and I will be back

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using old versions of React and Next
Update all your dependencies.

Comment: maybe there's something wrong with the browser. What version of Mozilla are you using? Latest?

Comment: I use the version 65.0 released two days ago

Comment: @Webwoman try to create a new app with React only installed (Babel, Webpack etc.). If there is a problem with React, post an issue on their repo, of if the problem is in Next.js, do the same on NextJS repo then.